# How I can send signal from MouseArea to parent object (TableView)?

Tags: qt, tableview, signals-slots

If I added MouseArea to TableView entity (to catch buttons etc.), then standard reaction in TableView doesn't response. Can I send signal from MouseArea to parent TableView?

```
TableView {                            

   TableViewColumn {
       role: "name"
       title: "Name"
       width: (parent.width / 2)
   }
   TableViewColumn {
       role: "type"
       title: "Type"
       width: parent.width / 4
   }
   TableViewColumn {
       role: "size"
       title: "Size"
       width: parent.width / 4
   }

   MouseArea {
       anchors.fill: parent
       acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton | Qt.LeftButton
       onClicked: {
           if (mouse.button == Qt.RightButton) {
              ...
           }
           else if(mouse.button == Qt.LeftButton){
              ...
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "send signal"?  Is there a specific signal in TableView or MouseArea that you want to emit, or...?

Comment: First answer is exactly what I want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can propagate it to parent with

```
propagateComposedEvents: true
```

and calling

```
mouse.accepted = false
```

in every needed handler.

From [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-mouseevent.html#accepted-prop):

> Setting accepted to true prevents the mouse event from being
>   propagated to items below this item.
>
> Generally, if the item acts on the mouse event then it should be
>   accepted so that items lower in the stacking order do not also respond
>   to the same event.

So next code:

```
   MouseArea 
   {
       anchors.fill: parent
       acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton | Qt.LeftButton
       propagateComposedEvents: true

       onPressed:
       {
           if (mouse.button == Qt.RightButton) {
               console.log("ss") 
           }
           else if(mouse.button == Qt.LeftButton){
               console.log("ss")
           }
           mouse.accepted = false
       }
       onReleased: mouse.accepted = false
       onPressAndHold:  mouse.accepted = false
   }
```

catches clicks (`console.log("ss")` works), but `tableview` get all events, so you can move columns, click on it etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this and my reaction on clicks working good. But I don't know, why items in TableView aren't clickable. It seems weird. ... I will be trying different combination.